# Bisection method program for sqrt(2)

Tags: python, printing, bisection

I am tasked with writing a program to do the bisection method to solve for the sqrt(2) with 6 iterations of the bisection method. Here is my code. I cannot get it to print the values along the way or in the end and I am not sure why.

```
import math
>>> def f(x):
    return (x**2)-2

>>> def bisect (a,b,n):
    while n < 6:
        c=(a+b)/2
    if f(c) == 0:
        print [('Root is: ', c)]
    elif f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        b=c
        n=(n+1)
        print [('n: ',n,' c: ',c)]
    else:
        a=c
        n=(n+1)
        print [('n: ',n,' c: ',c)]


>>> print bisect (0,1,0)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print bisect (0,1,0):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I immediately see two issues. First, in Python 3, you need to use parentheses around what you want to print (i.e., `print(bisect(0,1,0))`). This is what's causing your syntax error. Second, unless your indentation is wrong, your bisect function starts with an infinite loop, since it repeats while n < 6 but never increases n.